# Adding additional element to an existing JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a case like, I want to add elements into a JSON array in TypeScript like below

```
[ 
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
}
]
```

Now I want to add values to the above object without creating new block, for example, I want to add key, value pair as "C": "c1" and "d": "d1". After doing this, my JSON array must look like below

```
[ 
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
"c" : "c1",
"d" : "d1"
}
]
```

What I tried:

```
let someData : any [] = [];

someData.push({
"a" : "a1",
"b" : b1"
})

someData.push({
"c" : "c1",
"d" : d1"
})
```

But it is creating two records like below, but this is wrong

```
[ 
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
}
{
"c" : "c1",
"d" : "d1"
}
]
```

as well I tried using `unshift` as below

```
someData.unshift({
"c" : "c1",
"d" : d1"
})
```

this is returning result object as

```
[ 
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
}
{
"c" : "c1",
"d" : "d1"
}
]
```

Is there any way to do?

For example,

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
  someData.push({
    i : i+1
})
```

But the above block of code is creating wrong array structure, but inturn I want as below

```
{
0 :1,
1:2,
2:3
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried indexed interface in typescript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its supposed to be like this...

```
let someData : any [] = [];

someData.push({
"a" : "a1",
"b" : b1"
})

someData[0]["c"] = "c1";
someData[0]["d"] = "d1";
```

So when you log the values of `someData` ... it will show

```
console.log(someData); //[{"a":"a1","b" : "b1", "c":"c1", "d":"d1"}]
```

for looping through values...

```
let valuesToPut = [["c","c1"],["d","d1"]];

 for(let i = 0; i < valuesToPut.length; i++){
    someData[0][valuesToPut[i][0]] = valuesToPut[i][1]
 }
```

Comment: This is partially working.. the case it does not work is when you try putting a for loop and use the values like below
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
             someData[i]["c"] = "c1";            
        }

in this case it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken in my for loop, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you mensioned, it is an array json format.

So, if you access some element in the array, you should indicate the array index.

ex:

```
let tempArray = [ 
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
}
]
```

=> 
tempArray[0] has this value.

```
{
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
}
```

So, if you add some additional values to the tempArray[0], you should access the element like below :

```
tempArray[0]['c'] = "c1";
tempArray[0]['d'] = "d1";
```

Answer (score 1):

is little confusion between `Object` and `Array`, here you try to add some item to the `Object` who are store on index 0 of your array.

let try following code :

```
let someData : any [] = [];
// Create first index of array and create on it your Object.
someData.push({
    "a" : "a1",
    "b" : b1"
});

// Override first index of array by merge of previous data + new one.
someData[0] = Object.assign(someData[0], {
    "c1" : "c1",
    "d1" : "d1"
});
```

[Object assign documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign)

[Another way to do this: Object.defineProperties()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/defineProperties)

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Let's start with what you're doing
let someData = [];

someData.push({
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
});
// pushes a collection of 2 key value pairs in as the first entry to someData
someData.push({
"c" : "c1",
"d" : "d1"
});
// pushes a collection of 2 key value pairs in as the second entry to someData
console.log(someData);

// what you might want to do:
someData = [];

someData.push({
"a" : "a1",
"b" : "b1"
});
// pushes a collection of 2 key value pairs in as the first entry to someData
someData[0].c = "c1";
//Sets a value to the key c in the first element of some data
someData[0].d = "d1";
//Sets a value to the key d in the first element of some data
console.log(someData)

// What you probably want to do.
someData = {};
for(let i of [1,2,3,4]){
  someData[String.fromCharCode(i+96)] = String.fromCharCode(i+96)+"1";
}
console.log(someData)
```